# How can populate data in livewire component of this package "victorybiz/laravel-tel-input"

Tags: laravel

I am using this package to show phone input with tel, in my livewire php class I am setting data that I want to populate in the component this package provides

```
public function mount()
{
    $this->data['country_code'] = str_replace("+","",optional(user())->country_code);
    $this->data['phone_no'] = str_replace($this->data['country_code'],'',optional(user())->phone_no);

    $this->data['full_no'] = optional(user())->phone_no;
}
```

Here is my blade file and i have added a livewire component which they have suggested in the docs

```
<x-tel-input
            wire:model="phone"
            id="phone"
            name="phone"
            class="form-input"
        />
        <input wire:model="phone_country" type="hidden" id="phone_country" name="phone_country">
```

Here is the documentation link [Laravel Telephone Input](https://github.com/victorybiz/laravel-tel-input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By doing following I have achieved what I want to do
in a blade file

```
<x-tel-input
            wire:model="users.phone_no"
            id="phone_no"
            name="phone_no"
            class="form-input numeric form-control form-control-lg"
        />
        <input wire:model="users.country_code" type="hidden" id="country_code" name="country_code">
```

and in a PHP class mount function pass the values like this

```
public $users = [];
public function mount()
{
    $this->users['country_code'] = optional(user())->country_code;
    $this->users['phone_no']     = optional(user())->phone_no;
}
```

and also if you want to set livewire public property you can do this

```
@push('dashboard-js')
<script>
    phone_no.addEventListener('telchange', function(e) {
        @this.set("users.phone_no", e.detail.validNumber);
        @this.set("users.country_code", e.detail.dialCode);
    });
</script>
@endpush
```